# How to make vector2 handler in unity editor like in spriteRenderer or Joints

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to make that blue circles?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o6tm.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gizmos](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.html) and [Handles](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.html) to customize or use primitives and images to handler your editor scripts.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to workaroud, and I interested in built-in solution.